# How can I query YouTube API to get videos from auto-generated 'Topic' channels?

Tags: youtube, youtube-api, youtube-data-api

How can I input search parameters using the YouTube API so that I only get video ID's from topic channels? For instance, if I go to youtube.com and manually search "Hello Adele - Topic" I correctly get the song, 'Hello' from the 'Adele - Topic' channel as my first search result, https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_WS9w10ygpU.
However, if I perform the same query using the YouTube Data API, with the parameters:

```
part='snippet'
q='Hello Adele - Topic'
```

I won't get back the ID for the correct video. Is there any way to get this programmatically?

Answer (score 1):

As stated in this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44416398/5832311), auto generated channels have no videos. They have only playlists with videos from other channels. So you have to look for playlists. You may check the sample request in this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22599400/5832311).

> Here's the URL sample of auto-generated Topic-based Id which grabs its playlist id:
>
> ```
> GET https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/playlists?part=snippet&channelId=HC9m3exs6zk1U&fields=items%2Fid&key={YOUR_API_KEY}
> //Outputs sample playlist Id: LP9m3exs6zk1U
> ```
>
> Now here's the URL sample using that playlist Id to get the videos from the auto-generated Topic-based channel Id:
>
> ```
> GET https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/playlistItems?part=snippet&maxResults=5&playlistId=LP9m3exs6zk1U&key={YOUR_API_KEY} 
> //Outputs video data you want.
> ```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Hey thanks for the response. I'm not totally sure what it means that they have no videos. If you look at the link I posted as an example (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_WS9w10ygpU) it's clearly a video that's only available on the topic channel and has a video ID: _WS9w10ygpU. Is there any way to programmatically obtain this video ID?

Comment: @SkylarKennedy: that's probably YouTube transparently linking videos and causing them to appear as though they are part of that channel.  For Google to exclude them from the standard `search` API request is frustrating and asinine, but that's how it works (of course, it also consumes extra API credits for the additional requests you need to make)